# Number of partitions of a number

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

I've been trying to find out how many partitions of a number I can make if I restrict the partition size, The specific problem I am trying to tackle is,
How many ways can you partition the number '9' when each partition has a size less than or equal 6 but greater than 0 (note: all partitions have a discrete size ( can't have a decimal or fractional size)

My attempt:
let A+B+C=9 and let $(A,B,C)\subset S^3$ where $S= (x: where \ 6\ge x\ge 0)$
and then I did the stars and bars approach to finding the number of partitions $\binom{11}{2} $ but I am stuck on how to remove the partitions of where one of the partitions has is greater than 6. Is there any way to directly arrive at the answer required or more preferably a way to fix this formula?

Comment: Partitions of integer 9

Comment: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives compositions NOT partitions.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry https://brilliant.org/wiki/partition-of-an-integer/

Comment: From your link, the *compositions* of 5 are 5,41,14,32,23,311,131,113,221,212,122,2111,1211,1121,1112,11111 (16 in total - in fact there are $2^{n-1}$ compositions of $n$). Stars and bars enumerates these, and not partitions, which is what you are doing.

Comment: Stars and bars also allow 0 sized parts. For example, $\binom{5}{2}=10$ and this enumates compositions of 3 over 3 parts, including zero. These are 300,030,003,210,201,120,102,012,021,111 (10).

Comment: Is S supposed to allow $x\ge0$ or just $x\gt0$ as previously stated?

Comment: Greater than 0 , I figured how to remove the zero part, Just exclude the end positions as places where you can keep the dividers (subtracts 2 from total places)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read your question as: "On how many ways can we write $9$ as a sum of elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$? where the order of the terms does not matter."

---

If $T(n,k)$ denotes the number of ways that we can write non-negative integer $n$ as a sum of elements of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ then we have the recursion equality:$$T(n,k)=T(n,k-1)+T(n-k,k)$$The first term corresponds with the number of ways we can write $n$ as a sum of elements of $\{1,\dots,k-1\}$.

The second term corresponds with the number of ways we can write $n$ as a sum of elements of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ and moreover $k$ is one of the terms of this sum.

Also have a look Eulers triangular table at [A026820-OEIS](https://oeis.org/A026820) where I find that: $$T(9,6)=26$$

Comment: Your interpretation is correct but I don't know of eulers triangle or recursion formulas, If you could motivate these concepts it would be nice

Comment: I can only motivate the recursion formula (as I did in my answer). Further I generated some values and searched for it on OEIS. Then I found the triangle of Euler (new for me as well) and decided to mention it. The recursion formula allows you to find $T(9,6)$. Further there is no nice form of it.

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of partitions of $9$ into any parts, minus those with a part of size $7$, $8$ and $9$. So the number of partitions of $9$ is simply $30$. The number of partitions with a part of size at least $7$ is clearly
$$(9),\;\;(8,1),\;\;(7,2),\;\;(7,1,1)$$
so four. Thus there are $26$ partitions remaining.